# How can I input commands on cmd?

Tags: cmd

I'm trying out this Redis. I Was following some YouTube tutorials, but I cannot input commands on here. I need the `C:\Redis>` to type in commands but all I have is a flashing underscore:

[image]

EDIT: Hi, it is just a `ctrl + c` which closes the server but I was going to attach windows.conf to it so a new server connection is cool.

Comment: Please specify your problem clearly

Comment: maybe you'll have a better luck at [**http://ja.stackoverflow.com/**](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You need redis client(**redis-cli**). This is redis-server. If you have already downloaded then run redis-cli otherwise download and install redis-cli.